# How to call buildConfigField() from another function in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here's an extremely simplified version of what I'm trying to do in Gradle for my Android app:

```
android {

    buildTypes {

        debug {

            buildConfigFieldMyWay("keyName", "keyValue")
            buildConfigField("String", "keyName", "keyValue")  }
        }
    }

}

def buildConfigFieldMyWay(String keyName, String keyValue) {
    buildConfigField("String", keyName, keyValue)
}
```

The real version is more complex, which is why it would be nice to organize what I'm doing into separate functions.

The problem is that when I do a Gradle sync, I get this error:
`No signature of method: build_byqgds5lao5ipgp4gk5ftyud4.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_byqgds5lao5ipgp4gk5ftyud4$_run_closure2) values: [build_byqgds5lao5ipgp4gk5ftyud4$_run_closure2@536e468e]`

I think this has to do with the DSL Gradle uses with Android; that when `buildConfigField()` is called inside of `android { buildTypes { debug`, that it is running `buildConfigField()` on a `BuildType` object. If I call it from a separate function, there is no `BuildType` for it to operate on.

So I either need to modify the DSL so that my function (`buildConfigFieldMyWay()`) can be called  in `android { buildTypes { debug` and operate on the `BuildType` object, or I need to pass the `BuildType` to the function. There's likely some simple syntax I need to use here that I'm not finding. What is it?

Comment: You have used `buildConfigFieldForKey ` and `buildConfigFieldMyWay`. Did you mean to write the same name?

Comment: My bad, corrected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the build type inside the function `buildConfigFieldMyWay`:

```
def buildConfigFieldMyWay(buildType, String keyName, String keyValue) {
    buildType.buildConfigField("String", keyName, keyValue)
}
```

And then, you can get the build type using `it`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigFieldMyWay(it, "keyName", "keyValue")
            buildConfigField("String", "keyName", "keyValue")
        }
    }
}
```